# Logging React app state for analytics

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-analytics, redux, analytics

Since it's easy to convert React or Redux app state into JSON (and back), and since many companies with web app want to be able to gather as much data as possible about how users are using their app, it seems natural to me that you could just periodically send the JSONified app state to a server with a timestamp and some session tracking data, and keep a log of all app states across time.

If you had this, you'd probably also want a container app that let you replay the logged app state to watch what some given user has done.

My question is: is there any significant project out there that does this already? (SaaS? Open-source?)

I know this isn't a great stack overflow question format, but I'm surprised that this hasn't already been done and haven't found anything through Google or through asking around.

If you know what the name for this is (state playback user behavior analytics?) I will rename/re-tag this question.

Thank you!